# How to Disable the up and Down arrow keys for a silverlight listbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, listbox

I want to disable the navigation on press of UP and Down arrow keys in Silverlight.

I tried with a case statement:

```
void lisBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int numberofItems = lisBox.Items.Count-1;
        Keys key = (Keys)e.Key;
         switch (key)
         {
             case Keys.LEFT:
                 if (lisBox.SelectedIndex > 0)
                 {
                     lisBox.SelectedIndex = lisBox.SelectedIndex - 1;
                 }
                 break;
             case Keys.RIGHT:

                 if (lisBox.SelectedIndex < numberofItems)
                 {
                     lisBox.SelectedIndex = lisBox.SelectedIndex + 1;
                 }
                 break;
             case Keys.UP:
                e.Handled = true;
                lisBox.SelectedIndex = lisBox.SelectedIndex - 4;
                 break;
             case Keys.DOWN:
                    e.Handled = true;
                lisBox.SelectedIndex = lisBox.SelectedIndex - 4;
                 break;
         }

    }
```

This is not Workin :( . Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered at the following Post:

[KeyDown event is not working for Arrow keys, Home, End, PageUp, PageDown and other similar keys in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521362/keydown-event-is-not-working-for-arrow-keys-home-end-pageup-pagedown-and-othe)

Answer (score 0):

You want `e.Handled = true;`. If you say `false` you are saying "I didn't handle this so go ahead and let the default handler do its thing."

Comment: I tried Setting e.Handled = true. Even now the up and down keys works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the KeyUp event instead and say e.Handled=true...